# Как выбрать блок с определенными стилями? (php simple html dom parser)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

На странице есть такой блок:

```
<ul class="name1 class2">
     ...content...
</ul>
```

Мне нужно получить именно этот блок, так как на странице могут быть блоки типа

```
 <ul class="name1">....
 <ul class="class2">....
```

И такие мне не нужны.

Я делаю так:

```
$html->find('.name1 .class2');
```

Но в итоге ничего не получаю...

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А если так: $html->find('[class=name1], [class=class2]');

Comment: `$html->find('.name1.class2');` __без пробелов__